# Is there a way to add multiple lambda function for multiple intent in Amazon Lex V2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am using Amazon Lex V2 console to develop a bot. I want to use multiple lambda functions for multiple intents. For example *lambda-fun-1* for *intent1*, *lambda-fun-2* for *intent2* and so on.

I know we it is possible using V1 console, but not able to figure out on V2 console.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, an Amazon Lex V2 bot can be configured to use a single Lambda function per language.

[Amazon Lex V2 Lambda Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda.html?icmpid=docs_console_unmapped)

> You define the Lambda function to use in each bot alias. The same Lambda function is used for all intents in a language supported by the bot.

As can be seen, you can no longer define the Lambda function per intent. However, there is no reason why you cannot invoke use the single Lambda function that's configured for your bot's alias to call other Lambda functions based on the current intent's name.